# Error in webpart after upgrading to SharePoint Framework 1.8

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I have just upgraded to spfx framework version 1.8. When I try to add the webpart to the page, I get this error

```
Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/f2f8e00f-ef2a-4909-b24a-818262f88a19_0.0.1
    D.createContext is not a function
```

Built with React 16.7.0 and React-dom 16.7.0

Would appreciate any quick response or help